# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)' with alamofire swift3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

I've encountered following error while uploading Swift3 using XCode8.

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (_SwiftValue)'

```
let param: Parameters = [
    "email":txrNRC.text as AnyObject,
    "password":txtPassword.text as AnyObject
]
```

Please let me know how to solve that issue. I've already tried with `let param: NSDictionary` but got same error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all in Swift 3 the Objective-C equivalent of `id` is `Any` rather than `AnyObject`, that avoids also the `AnyObject` castings.

The error message indicates that an illegal type is used (`Parameters`), JSON supports only `string`, `number`, `<null>` and `array` / `dictionary`.

In your case the dictionary is `[String:String]`, a type annotation is not needed at all

```
let param = [
    "email" : txrNRC.text,
    "password" : txtPassword.text
]
```

If `txrNRC` and `txtPassword` are optionals you need to unwrap them or use the nil coalescing operator to assign a placeholder if the value is `nil`

Comment: if that so, Optional("") is included.